# Знаки вопроса в UIPickerView и некорректный вывод ответа из формулы

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Пишу программу основанной на формуле, проще говоря калькулятор годовой оценки. Есть формула: баллы за контрольную четвертей складываются и делятся на сумму максимального балла и умножаются на коефициент. Первая проблема из всего этого - выводятся знаки вопроса в pickerview. Гуглил, не помогло. Вторая проблема, это значения в ответе не полные. То есть значения после запятой не выводятся, только округленные числа. Я только начал изучать данную среду программирования, прошу подсказать где кроется мой косяк. Есть label и pickerview.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    var num : NSArray = Array(0...240) as NSArray
    var sum = 0
    var sum1 = 0
    var sum2 = 0
    var sum3 = 0
    var sum4 = 0
    var sumTotal = 0
    var sumPart1 = Double()
    var sumPart2 = Double()
    let vsoKoef = Double(42)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self
    }

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return num.count
    }

    private func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int! {
        return num[row] as! Int
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if (component == 0) {
            sum1 = num[row] as! Int
        }
        if (component == 1) {
            sum2 = num[row] as! Int
        }
        if (component == 2) {
            sum3 = num[row] as! Int
        }
        if (component == 3) {
            sum4 = num[row] as! Int
        }
        if (component == 4) {
            sumTotal = num[row] as! Int
        }
        sum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + sum4
        if sum > 0 && sumTotal != 0 {
            sumPart1 = Double(sum / sumTotal)
        }
        if sum > 0 && sumTotal != 0 && sumPart1 > 0 {
            sumPart2 = sumPart1 * vsoKoef
        }
        if sum > 0 && sumTotal != 0 && sumPart1 > 0 && sumPart2 > 0 {
            label.text = "\(sumPart2)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это какая версия Swift у Вас?

Comment: Version 8.3 (8E162)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала ознакомьтесь глубже с основами Swift, тогда некоторые вещи пойдут легче. Давайте по порядку.

**1** Так не принято писать:

```
var sumPart1 = Double()
```

Тип выведется сам:

```
var sumPart1 = 0.0
```

**2** Если у Вас просто числа от 0 до 240,

```
var num : NSArray = Array(0...240) as NSArray
```

то не нужно в этом случае создавать массив. Да еще и приводить к NSArray. Просто укажите:

```
var num = 241
```

**3** Проблема неточности рассчетов заключается в том, что Вы сначала делите два Int, а затем приводите к Double:

```
sumPart1 = Double(sum / sumTotal)
```

Сначала приведите к Double:

```
sumPart1 = Double(sum) / Double(sumTotal)
```

**4** Ну и знаки вопросов - как указано в ответе выше. Только без override. Итого должно получитсья по Вашему коду примерно следующее:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    var num = 241
    var sum = 0
    var sum1 = 0
    var sum2 = 0
    var sum3 = 0
    var sum4 = 0
    var sumTotal = 0
    var sumPart1 = 0.0
    var sumPart2 = 0.0
    let vsoKoef = 42.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self
        print("asd")
        print(Array(0...240))

        print("asdasd")
    }

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return num
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return String(row)
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if (component == 0) {
            sum1 = row
        }
        if (component == 1) {
            sum2 = row
        }
        if (component == 2) {
            sum3 = row
        }
        if (component == 3) {
            sum4 = row
        }
        if (component == 4) {
            sumTotal = row
        }
        sum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + sum4
        if sum > 0 && sumTotal != 0 {
            sumPart1 = Double(sum) / Double(sumTotal)
        }
        if sum > 0 && sumTotal != 0 && sumPart1 > 0 {
            sumPart2 = sumPart1 * vsoKoef
        }
        if sum > 0 && sumTotal != 0 && sumPart1 > 0 && sumPart2 > 0 {
            label.text = "\(sumPart2)"
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот это да! спасибо огромное за помощь! Я еще в процессе изучения, смотрю разные туториалы и не везде скажут именно то что нужно на деле. Учту свои ошибки и буду изучать дальше)

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте

```
 private func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int! {
    return num[row] as! Int
}
```

на

```
private func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return "\(num[row])"
```

}

[Дока](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614384-pickerview) говорит что метод должен вернуть строку или nil, а у вас он возвращает Int

Comment: Ошибка: "method does not override any method from its superclass" и указывает на pickerView перед func. Честно, не знаю в чем причина =(

Comment: обновил, ну и в ответе ниже уже отписали все ошибки

Comment: и Вам спасибо =)